# As3 Cursor rotating according to Mouse's x coordinate

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse-cursor

Below you can find what i meant. I need my movie clip to rotate as i go different X positions.

http://www2.mediamind.com/creative_zone/movistar_agua_wallpaper_msn/index.html

Rotating according to X position function is enough for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Got any other examples? That link doesn't seem to illustrate any rotating cursor.

Comment: When you click the 300x250 banner usb stick it will expand and you will se the rotating usb

Answer (score 0):

refer a following site tutorial:
[mouse-follow-with-easing-smooth-rotation-v2](http://www.freeactionscript.com/2011/01/mouse-follow-with-easing-smooth-rotation-v2/)